# Webpages slow, unresponsive on one Mac – but not another Mac on the same network

Tags: macos, network, safari, google-chrome, time-capsule

I'm experiencing a particular website that is extremely slow (unresponsive, to be honest) on one of my Macs, but not another Mac on my home network. My iPad is also responsive.

There may be more webpages that are problematic, but this one in particular has been troublesome for a few days.

I have disabled the antivirus and all security related extensions in my main browser. I've cleared the cache of my main browser. I have the exact same problem in another browser, which use Default settings.

Why is this page impossible on my Mac, but snappy and responsive on the other devices on my home network?

Is there an OS X "system" cache that needs to be flushed, in regards to web browsing? I'm thinking something like DNS, etc.

All my devices connect to the net through the same router, which is an Apple TimeCapsule.

Comment: What page is it? It might be the page that is causing the problem.

Comment: @EdricChan Could be, but the computers are pretty much identical in browser-terms, using same Chrome user account/plugins and Default Safari settings. But if there isn't a "cache" somrwhere on the computer or router that needs to be flushed, then I suppose it's the webpage causing the issue.

Comment: Here's how to flush the DNS: [https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT202516](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT202516)